# Creating exception for specific subdirectory in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, flask

This should be a simple problem to solve, but I'm struggling to find a solution that works.

I have recently deployed a Flask application, which is working fine except for an issue with my .htaccess file. The application is deployed in a subdirectory (which is supposed to be reachable at `mysite.com/flaskapp`) alongside a wordpress blog (`mysite.com`) that works fine with the below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have found that if I delete the content of the .htaccess file, the flask application works well, but none of the wordpress links beyond the front page work. Conversely, with the content above intact the wordpress install works, but every URL in `mysite.com/flaskapp/*` gives a 'post not found' message from the WordPress site.

As a result I assume the setup I need is to somehow not have the above rewrite rules active for any url beginning with `mysite.com/flaskapp`, but feel free to correct me if this assumption is wrong.

**What do I need to do the the .htaccess file to resolve this so that both the wordpress blog and the Flask application work?**

---

**UPDATE:** There is also a .htaccess file in the flask application's directory, in case that changes or explains anything:

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/user/flaskapp"
PassengerBaseURI "/flaskapp"
PassengerPython "/home/user/virtualenv/ratings/3.6/bin/python3.6"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a line like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory
```

after the other RewriteCond lines, replacing "directory" with "flaskapp" or the name of the directory to exclude.

The flask application's htaccess shouldn't need any altering.